# React native state not updating

Tags: react-native

I feel like Im going crazy here.....
I type in "x" to the searchbar but `this.setState({ filter: text });` is not updating state.... `console.log(this.state.filter);` gives me a value of '' (its initial value set in constructor).
I can see the value of text variable is x...but its just not updating the filter state.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 30 * 60,
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0,
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      pagetoken: null,
      refreshing: false,
      waiting4answer: false,
      placeName: null,
      placeUri: null,
      filter: '',
    };
```

}

```
renderHeader = () => {
    if (this.state.waiting4answer === false) return null;
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        lightTheme
        round
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({ filter: text });
          console.log(this.state.filter);
          this.searchFilterFunction();
        }}
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: ```setState``` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Use a ```Text``` component to display the value

Comment: Can we know the expected output ? state wont update just after you use setstate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state is updating, it's just the way that you are checking and using the updated state is flawed.

### State is Asynchronous

State is asynchronous, it takes time for the state to set. The problem you are encountering is that you are calling `setState` and then immediately logging the value from state. Unfortunately when you do this the state will not have updated by this time you log it, so you are getting the previous value.

### State takes a callback

If you want to use the value of state that you have just set then you need to use the `callback` function that `setState` has. `this.setState({key: value}, callback)`

This callback allows you to run functions after the state has been set. You can use it in the following way:

```
this.setState({filter: text}, () => {
  // put the things you wish to occur after you have set your state.
  console.log(this.state.filter);
 
  // I am guessing your searchFilterFunction requires the updated filter value in state 
  // so put that here too
  this.searchFilterFunction();
});
```

This means that once you set the value of `filter` in the state and the state has updated to reflect that value it will then run the `callback`, so it will log the value of `filter` that is now in state, and then it will run the `searchFilterFunction`.

### Further reading

You can read more about state in this series of great articles by Michael Chan

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

Answer (score 1):

use the setState callback to get the updated state immediately after setting it

```
this.setState({ filter: text }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.filter);
});
```

react setState is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronou)